# Splitting large HTML file in PHP by HTML element (e.g. TABLE)

Tags: php, memory, generator

I'm trying to parse a relatively large HTML file (20 mb) in PHP.   The HTML file contains some 200 tables (TABLE tag) with on average 50-100 rows per table.  I want to clean up and save the Table HTML on a database. The code works,  but takes up too much memory and is very slow.

The HTML table is an export from a legacy SAP system and the entire file is in a single line,  therefore some of the techniques involving line by line processing cannot be used.

How do I improve this code to do what it does but doesn't take as much time and to excecute faster.  Here's what I'm using

```php
$file = file_get_contents('ro_full.html');

$doc = new DOMDocument();


@$doc->loadhtml($file);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

// Modify the XPath query to match the content
$i=0;
foreach($xpath->query('//table') as $table) {
    echo "<br><br>---TABLE ".$i." ----<br>";

    $tableHTML= $table->C14N();
    echo preg_replace("/<([a-z][a-z0-9]*)[^>]*?(\/?)>/i",'<$1$2>', $tableHTML);
    $i++;

}
```

Comment: 20MB is large for an HTML file but isn't really that big for DomDocument to handle. Are you sure that is the bottleneck?  You should benchmark different parts of this to figure out exactly what is causing the slowdown. If it does turn out to be the size of your HTML, https://www.php.net/XMLReader is a tool that can parse X(HT)ML without fully loading it into memory.

Comment: Thank you.  I abandoned this and went for a text file